# How do I see how many views a YouTube playlist has?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I created [a YouTube playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL17C986CA3CEED034&feature=mh_lolz). How do I see how many views the playlist has acquired? I **don't** want to see how many channel views I have, I want to see **playlist** views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube has removed this in the latest UI update. Most likely it was underused and didn't fit anywhere in the new UI so they removed it.

Comment: So there's no way at all?

Comment: @daviesgeek try a query in the api I guess, if it's still there

Comment: Yeah your best bet is what @phwd said but it may not be easy to do as a newbie. Maybe make another question about that.

Comment: @phwd Thanks! I will create a new question for that. It doesn't belong on here, does it?

Comment: Never mind, don't know what I was thinking. Posted [the question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458423/can-i-retrieve-youtube-playlist-views-through-the-youtube-api)

Comment: @daviesgeek okay best of luck to you. (hit the check mark if this answered your question)